# Need to have separate "complete" Drupal theme for each page on a site

Tags: drupal-6, themes

I want to build a Drupal demonstration site where I can create several custom themes and display each on a separate page of the site.  Access can be either via links or menu items.  The "simpler" the solution the better.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom block that executes PHP code. The following code snippet should show the current page in the theme set in `$custom_theme`.

```
global $custom_theme, $theme;

// If $theme is set, init_theme() will not initialize the custom theme.
unset($theme);

// Set the theme you want to use.
$custom_theme = "garland";
init_theme();
```

There is also a module that allows you to change the used theme based on some rules (in example, the content type being showed, the URL of the page being viewed, etc): the project page is http://drupal.org/project/themekey.